# Remove a common prefix from many files at once

Tags: bash, unix, find, pipe, cp

I have to perform the following action on multiple files within a single folder:

> Remove "Sword of the Stranger - " part from the file names like "Sword of the Stranger - Aganai No Yuki - ストレンヂア無皇刃譚 - [20-25].mp3".

To do that I have constructed following command:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec sh -c "cp {} `echo {} | cut -f2- -d'-' | cut -c2-`" \;
```

But on executing the above command I get the following error:

```
cp: target ‘}’ is not a directory
```

Even if I change the above command to account for spaces in the file names, it still gives me the same error.

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec sh -c "cp {} "`echo {} | cut -f2- -d'-' | cut -c2-`"" \;
```

Please someone explain why I am getting the error and suggest another one liner to do the above operation (preferably using find and exec and cp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that double-quotes do not prevent command substitution; that is, something like this:

```
echo "`echo foo`"
```

prints `foo` rather than `` `echo foo` ``.

So in your example, the command substitution happens *before* `find` is called. That is, this:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec sh -c "cp {} `echo {} | cut -f2- -d'-' | cut -c2-`" \;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec sh -c "cp {} }" \;
```

because the command `echo {} | cut -f2- -d'-' | cut -c2-` prints `}`.

To fix this, you can use single-quotes instead.

Additionally, you'll need to use double-quotes in a few places in your command in order to prevent your filenames from being interpreted as multiple arguments to `echo` and to `cp`:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec sh -c 'cp "{}" "`echo "{}" | cut -f2- -d- | cut -c2-`"' \;
```

(Note that I've also changed `-d'-'` to `-d-`. These are equivalent anyway, so there's no need to do anything fancy to get the `-d'-'` inside a single-quoted string.)

Comment: I used the command with single quotes as you have mentioned. Also i put the `` part inside "" to account for spaces of filename and now i get a new error:     `cp: target ‘Sora No Hate Made - ストレンヂア無皇刃譚 - [25-25].mp3’ is not a directory`

Comment: @tom: Updated to address the spaces in your filenames. (You need more than just the one set of `""`.)

Comment: Yeah i worked this time but can you explain me why that `not a directory` error was there?

Comment: @tom: The command `cp foo bar` is ambiguous: it means either "copy `foo` to new filename `bar`" or "copy `foo` into the directory `bar`", depending on whether `bar` already exists as a directory. But the command `cp foo bar baz` *always* means "copy `foo` and `bar` into the directory `baz`", so it gives an error if `baz` isn't already a directory. In your case, your command was something like `cp Sword of the Stranger - Sora No Hate Made - ストレンヂア無皇刃譚 - [25-25].mp3 "Sora No Hate Made - ストレンヂア無皇刃譚 - [25-25].mp3"`.

Comment: Yeah i was just typing the same thing :) .

Comment: Using `{}` in the argument passed to `sh -c` isn't safe. `find` can't quote it correctly to make it safe. Don't do that. **Always** pass `{}` as the *argument* to `sh` and use `$1` in the script (i.e. `-exec sh -c 'echo "$1"' - {}` the `-` fills in `$0`).